# Show the inclusions $\mathcal L^r(\lambda) \subseteq \mathcal L^s(\lambda)$ and $L^s(\lambda) \subseteq \mathcal L^r(\lambda)$ doesn't hold.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Suppose $0 < r < s < \infty$ and $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure on $(\mathbb R, \mathcal B(\mathbb R))$.

I want to show that $\mathcal L^r(\lambda) \subseteq \mathcal L^s(\lambda)$ and $L^s(\lambda) \subseteq \mathcal L^r(\lambda)$ is **not** true.

To do so, I consider the functions $x \mapsto x^{-1/s}$ and $x \mapsto x^{-1/r}$.

However when integrating, both $\int^{\infty}_0 x^{-r/s} \lambda(dx)$ and $\int^{\infty}_0 x^{-s/s} \lambda(dx)$ evaluate to $\infty$, so I cannot conclude whether one function belongs to one class and not the other.

I've also looked into the case $\mathcal L^r(\lambda) \subseteq \mathcal L^{\infty}(\lambda)$ and $L^{\infty}(\lambda) \subseteq \mathcal L^r(\lambda)$.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why form 0 to $\infty$? You can take *any* interval:
$$\int_0^1 x^\alpha dx=\cdots$$
$$\int_1^\infty x^\alpha dx=\cdots$$

About the $L^\infty$ case, for the first noninclusion you want an unbounded function (already seen in the previous cases) and the second noninclusion is even easier.

Comment: In fact from $-\infty$ to $\infty$, but you can take from 0 to $\infty$ or... *any interval*.